# Apache does not forward requests to Nodejs backend server

Tags: node.js, apache, centos

I have the following configuration file for my vhost.conf I have tried literally every possible configuration out there to get proxying to work, but without any success. I have a nodejs backend server listening on port 3000 and i cannot forward requests to it. If i access the server ip address and remove any vhost it works fine, but when i add any vhost.conf i get the "Service Unavailable" message in the browser. Can someone help? Thx.
Below is my vhost.conf file. I do not have a domain name, i am using my server's ip address to resolve incoming requests.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    
    ServerName localhost

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

For some odd reason i needed to add the `<IfModule mod_proxy.c></ifModule>` tags to make it work. I did set up a lot of servers and i didn t need this tag before. Oh well, it took me 1 day to figure this out.

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName localhost

    <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
     ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/ retry=0 timeout=5
     ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
    </IfModule>

 </VirtualHost>
```